# Increasing elements in a data structure that follows the Composite pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I have often read/heard that the composite pattern is a good solution to represent hierarchical data structures like binary trees, which it is great to explain this pattern because internal nodes are `composite` objects and leaves are `leaf` objects. I can appreciate that using this pattern, it is easy to visit every element in an uniform way.

However, I am not so sure if it is the best example if you are considering that a tree is filling on demand (every time an `insert` method is executed) because we have to convert a `leaf` to `composite` object many times (e.g. when `leaf` has to add a child). To convert a `leaf` object, I imagine a tricky way like (inspired by `become:` from Smalltalk I guess):

```
aComposite = aLeaf.becomeComposite();
aComposite.addChild(newElement);
//destroy aLeaf (bad time performance)
```

To sum up, Is a good example the use of a tree-like structure to illustrate the composite pattern if this kind of structure is born commonly empty and then you have to add/insert elements?

Comment: See below. I had a go at answering your question as I understood it, but for sure ask for more clarification if I missed the mark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoF states the **Intent** of Composite as follows:

"Compose objects into **tree structures** to represent part-whole hierarchies. .....  treat individual object and compositions of objects uniformly"

So a tree is not so much a structure to illustrate Composite, rather **a tree is the structure by which composite is defined and operates**. Its also worth remembering that for the purposes of Composite, a tree can be a binary tree (2 children), a linked list (one child) or can be composed of nodes with a variable number of children .

Its quite normal to build a tree from nothing. Consider an arithmetic expression parser, building a composite "parse" tree. The parser will start from nothing and create leaf nodes for terminal symbols (like + - * / braces, numbers) and composite nodes to combine the terminals perform the calculations. The parser constructs the tree such that invoking evaluate() on the head node will cause a traversal to evaluate the expression.

I use this example to show that a tree can be built bottom up, never having to "convert a leaf to composite object".

If your application builds the tree top down, or progressively in stages, its hard to see that matters, because the build process will consist of creating appropriate nodes and inserting them in a way that makes sense for the application.

If converting leaf nodes to composite nodes is problematic in any specific application, then for sure you make to look at ways to minimise the overhead in that situation. but its only a valid Composite structure when the tree is built!

Comment: Ok, I like the answer. However, you says that composite pattern for tree-like structures is ok when you already have the final representation of the tree, but no when the tree is evolving with more or less elements during the time. I can understand both examples (math expressions and parsers), but you suppose the tree structure is already complete. IMHO, previous kinds of examples are very common/easy to illustrate composite pattern benefits.

Comment: If you have a situation where the tree is being constantly re-built (say feeding different expressions to the parser) or some business situation that requires the tree to be adjusted, its all still Composite, provided when the tree or some iteration can be "executed" from the head node and the all nodes have the logic to traverse the tree. Are we saying the same thing, or do you see it differently still?